# Stream output to stdout after spawning `git clone`

Tags: javascript, node.js, git

I'm just trying to run `git clone` from node and stream the output into stdout just like running from shell normally would, but after using `child_process.spawn`, I can't get the output to pipe into stdout. Currently I'm using:

```
child = spawn('git', ['clone', url]);
child.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
child.stderr.pipe(process.stderr);
```

But I only see "Cloning into 'directory'" message and not the remote messages and "Receiving objects...".

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `git clone` only shows progress when it's running in a terminal. When it's not running in a terminal progress can be enabled with the [`--progress` argument](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#git-clone---progress):

> Progress status is reported on the standard error stream by default when it is attached to a terminal, unless -q is specified. This flag forces progress status even if the standard error stream is not directed to a terminal.

However I'm not sure that that will do exactly what you expect. The progress output isn't simple output; values change in place. I'm not exactly sure how nicely that will play with `child_process.spawn()`.

Note also that output is to `STDERR`, not `STDOUT`.

Comment: Clone and fetch also don't pass the `--progress` argument on to `git receive-pack` so things don't work right here in general. The cure is to allocate a pseudo-tty, but it's rarely worth all the work.

Comment: thanks! tried it and it works perfectly. i'm not sure how the variable output thing works either though